# How to customize an activity as progress page , showing GIF and animation on switching between activity?

Tags: java, android

I need to show my own customized progress-bar to run GIF or animate to show progress fitting to my phone display. I need your suggestions for implemenation.

Comment: @pskink  i having an idea to customize activity as progress bar- running gif-images or animating sequential image. I know about idea, but cant able to implement.

Answer (score -1):

It is not a good idea to have an activity for displaying loading progress for other activities.

The reason is that your loading activity doesn't have an easy way of knowing whether the data has loaded.

---

Here's what you can do to accomplish what you want:

1. Since you said you want a custom progress bar, create a **loading_layout.xml**:

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       id="@+id/loading_layout">
       ...
       <ProgressBar .../>
       ...
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. In the layout of each activity you want to display the loading, include the layout. For example, if you'd like to show a `UserProfileActivity`:

   ```
   <RelativeLayout>

       <!-- main layout -->
       <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/main_layout"
           android:visibility="gone">
           <!-- Display user info -->
       </LinearLayout>

       <include layout="@layout/loading_layout" />

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```

In your activity, after loading has finished, simply set the *loading layout* visibility to `gone` and the *main layout* to `visible`.

Another way to achieve this is to have:
1. A fragment with the loading indication: `LoadingFragment`
1. A fragment with the main layout: `UserProfileFragment`
1. Display `LoadingFragment` until the data loads and then switch to `UserProfileFragment`.

Comment: Its possible to make activity as "Loading Screen".